# How to read the whole file and line by line file in the same Perl script

Tags: perl

Whenever I want Perl to read the whole file I put `undef $/` before reading the file. I tried to find more information about the variable `$/` but without success.

What I need to do is to write a script in Perl that first reads the whole file to a variable and then read another file line by line. How could this be done?

Comment: read http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles for more information on `$/`, and why `undef $/` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try opening and reading the first file in a local scope, and then limit the setting of `$/` to that scope.

```
my $firstfile;
{
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die;
    local $/ = undef;
    $firstfile = <$fh>;
    close $fh;
}

# continue with $/ still set
```

Link:

http://perlmaven.com/slurp (section: localize the change)

Either that, or save the value of `$/` to another variable before setting it to `undef`, and then reset it after reading the first file.

If you don't want to use `$/`, look into `File::Slurp`. There is a section on using it in the link I provided.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it without directly using $/.

You can use [File::Slurp's read_file](http://search.cpan.org/~uri/File-Slurp-9999.19/lib/File/Slurp.pm#read_file) to read the first file and store its data in memory.

```
my $text = read_file('filename');
my $bin = read_file('filename' { binmode => ':raw' });
my @lines = read_file('filename');
my $lines = read_file('filename', array_ref => 1);
```

And, the [simplest reading method](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) to read the second file line by line.

```
open(my $fh, '<', 'input.txt');
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    ...
}
close $fh;
```